# how to merge only column in devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

i have two column null value in DataTable as datasource component gridcontrol, and column automatically merge cell if same value null.
how to merge only column in devexpress??

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E559

Comment: @andy : thank`s for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable cell merging, it's necessary to set the [GridView.OptionsView.AllowCellMerge](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_AllowCellMergetopic) property to true.If you want to customize the merge condition then you can define merging rule using the [GridView.CellMerge](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CellMergetopic) event.

e.g.

```
gridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].OptionsColumn.AllowMerge = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
```

//Event -- Change it as per your requirement

```
private void gridView1_CellMerge(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CellMergeEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView view = sender as GridView;
            try
            {
                if ((e.Column.FieldName == "ColumnName"))
                {
                    object value1 = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle1, e.Column);
                    object value2 = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle2, e.Column);

                    e.Merge = (value1 == value2)||(value1 == null || value2 == null);
                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Reference:
[How to merge grid cells](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E559)
[Cell Merging Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1461)